# (standard_in) 1: syntax error when bc within if

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, bc

Getting the error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

When running the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do time=$(echo $line|awk '{print $10}'|awk -F"=" '{print $2}')
if (( $(echo "$time > 100" | bc -l) ))
then echo $line
fi
done  < ping.txt
```

The ping.txt file contains lines like below:

```
2018-08-15 13:45:54: 64 bytes from server.my.local (192.168.1.117): icmp_seq=7163 ttl=62 time=327 ms
```

basically i am trying to find all lines where time > 100 ms

Comment: This works for me, can't reproduce. I suspect that your logic to extract the time field fails on some lines and you end up with something that's not a number in `time`, but for the example input line, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk -F'[ =]' '$(NF-1)>100' ping.txt
```

The time is the second-to-last field `$(NF-1)` when split using `[ =]`.